# how to redo/avoid linebreak in console?

Tags: java, terminal, bufferedreader

I would like to redo a line break in the console.

For example if I use:

```
reader.readLine();
```

and the user enters some input and returns
then the cursor is in a new line.

| ... cursor

> : input
> [enter]
>
> : |

I would like to read the input but stay in the
same line and if the user again presses enter
a new line occurs.

> : input [enter] |

How would I achieve that ?

Comment: Make your own console in a GUI window. For that there is already code. Real console handling has its libraries though, partly even with coloring.

Comment: @ Joop Eggen I would like to use the std. terminal

Comment: I think you are simply looking for a loop, where you have `reader.readLine();` in a loop. This is not the best example, but you need something like `while(true) { reader.readLine(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a some input: ");
        String userInput = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Received input: " + userInput);
    }
}
```

Side note from personal experience, do not declare the scanner in a try-with-resources block if you intend on using the System.in stream again, as it will close the stream without any means of reopening the stream without restarting the process.